# Move layout above bottom sheet when it opens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I want base layout which is currently a included `RecyclerView` move above `Bottomsheet` when it opens. Same like `adjustResize` behaviour.

I tried to set anchor but it does not seem to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/llDefault"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar_single_chat" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOnlineStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_small"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_green"
            android:padding="@dimen/space_small"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="Online" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <include
                layout="@layout/layout_recycler_view_default"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/peek_height_bottomsheet"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomSheet"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
                layout="@layout/layout_bottom_options_single_chat" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

I am stuck since 1 hour in this.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"` to `app:layout_anchorGravity="top"`

Note:-
And to get the advantages of coordinator layout behaiour features , the views need to be direct child of the corrdinator layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think in case of bottom sheet adjustResize like behaviour can not be achieved instead you can include a layout which can be attached to the bottom of coordinator layout

Comment: That's not like that. My included layout's parent node has property layoutBehaviour so I am able to set it all. that's not the problem.

Comment: You can try making an sample with your solution, with not including, anchorGravity does not work for match_parent view.